# Extra character received in a json response

Tags: php, json

This php file returns a Jason encoded response. But my problem is that besides the Jason encodec response it also puts "<" in fron of the response.[Here its a picture with the response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9FOF.png)
How can I remove it?

```
<?php

        require 'connection.php';

      if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {


        $username = $_POST["username"];

        $password = $_POST["password"];



        $statement = mysqli_prepare($idCon, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);



        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_ID, $name, $username, $password);



        $response = array();

        $response["success"] = false;  



        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

            $response["success"] = true;  

            $response["name"] = $name;

            $response["username"] = $username;

            $response["password"] = $password;

        }



        echo json_encode($response);
      }
      else{
        $response = array();
            $response["success"] = false;
            echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

The connection php file (I replaced the date from $nameUser,$pass,$bazaDeDate with "***"):

```
 <?php

        $nameServer="localhost"; 
        $nameUser="******";
        $pass="*****";
        $bazaDeDate="****";

        $idCon=mysqli_connect($nameServer,$nameUser,$pass);
        if(!$idCon)
            die ('Con failed');

        $rezultatSelectBD=mysqli_select_db($idCon,$bazaDeDate);
        if(!$rezultatSelectBD)
            die ('Con failed');


    ?>
```

Comment: Trim(), ltrim(), substr(), preg_replace(). Did you try any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your php opening tags in your original script. if you cant find the error the omit parts of code one by one till you find the code where you left this  "<" symbol